# Perl - Join two array elements together

Tags: perl

I'm looking for the best way to concatenate two array elements together:

```
@array1 = (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);

@array2 = (answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5);
```

I want to concatenate array1 & array2 together to form the below pipe delimited array element. What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
@array3 = (test1|answer1, test2|answer2, test3|answer3, test4|answer4, test5|answer5);
```

Comment: Please try something on your own perl coding and it will helps better for you.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish? I'm wondering if a hash is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use these codes,the loop is easy.

```
my @array1 = qw/test1 test2 test3 test4 test5/;
my @array2 = qw/answer1 answer2 answer3 answer4 answer5/;
my @array3 = map { $array1[$_]."|".$array2[$_] } 0..$#array1;
```

This assumes both arrays have the same size.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation for the last line?

Comment: @JohnDoe Sure.Map function is useful.Just like:for($i=0;$i<=$#arrar1;$i++){push(@array3,$array1[$_]."|".$array2[$_])}